# NoMethodError in Articles#show but instance variables match? undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h1>Showing article details</h1>

<p><strong>Title: </strong><%= @article.title %></p>
<p><strong>Description: </strong><%= @article.description %></p>
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_08_043002) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :articles, only: [:show]
end
```

New to Ruby so I'm not sure what I did wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here. You should use `byebug` to drop into a REPL debugging environment and make sure your controller action and view are the ones you think are being called.

Comment: @IshaanBrissette looks like that `@article` variable is nil, which probably means `Article#find` didn't return any results. I'd check to make sure that `params[:id]` is set to the value you're expecting, and that there is indeed a record in the database for that `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the code. When you create a route like `resources :articles, only: [:show]` it generates a GET method like `/articles/:id`. So when you call the show action make sure you have value for `id` included in the path, like `localhost:3000/articles/779` for example.

If the id is not present in the path then the controller doesn't know the value of params. ie `params[:id]` will be `nil`. This makes `@article = nil`. Thus `@article.title` leads to this error in your view. Please check if this is the possible error happening.